# I need a loop to run until toggle button is pressed again without pausing

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3b to collect data over SPI from a time-to-digital converter (TDC-GPX2). The TDC essentially marks when in sees an event (rising edge of an electrical pulse let's say) and sends its timing information to my Pi. My goal for this would be to collect data without pause (as missed pulses increase error chance in my data), as fast as possible, until a toggle is flipped off.

Note: We are developing LVDS comm drivers on our FPGA for faster data acquisition from the TDC, but this would help with quick tests and other projects. We're using spidev for the SPI
Also: I realize requesting all 4 stops' information isn't efficient but I can adjust that later

I'm using Kivy as the gui solution for this software, I'll show the important snippets of code below. I'm using a main code with the gui and a library for the TDC with the loop inside it. I've never posted here before so I'm not sure what to include in the code, if more is needed I'll post it! I did try the "thread" library but it seemed to be really unresponsive and slowed down the gui dramatically.

```
def press_callback(obj):
    global tdcinit, f
    print("Button pressed,",obj.text)

    if obj.text == 'Read TDC':
        if obj.state=="down":
            f.write("New Trial \r\n")
            TDC.ReadTDC(f,obj.state)
        else:
            TDC.ReadTDC(f,obj.state)
            TDC.Reset()
            print('Done Recording, plz save before close')
```

the button definition down lower is:

```
Class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout=GridLayout(cols=5)
        Window.clearcolor(0.2,0.2,0.2,1)
        TDCRead = ToggleButton(text='Read TDC')
        TDCRead.bind(on_press=press_callback)
        layout.add_widget(TDCRead)

        return layout
```

The function in my TDC library being called is:

```
def ReadTDC(self,f,state):
    while state=='down':
        GPIO.output(29,0) #this is just for SPI
        i=8
        j=1
        self.__transfer(0x68)
        while i<32:
            byteback = self.__transfer(0x00)
            if j<4:
                f.write("Ref: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
                j=j+1
            elif j>=4 and j<6:
                f.write("Res: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
            else:
                f.write("Res: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
                j=1
            i=i+1
        GPIO.output(29,1)
    return f
```

The __transfer function is really just using xfer2 and printing the results for debugging.

I had hoped this would work as a "Press ToggleButton named Read TDC and the loop runs until I press the toggle again," but it just focused the loop until I ctrl+C'd my way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up figuring this out and here's how I got it working (again may not be the most optimal code, but it has been tested). Again this is using Kivy and Python 3 on  my Raspberry pi. I added this to my initialization:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

q = Queue()
```

I had to add this definition to use the multiprocessing library (I write to a file, you can choose to ignore this if you don't need to):

```
def readprocess(qstate):
    f = open("TDCData.txt","a+")
    f.write("New Trial \r\n")
    print('reading process began')
    run = True
    while run:
        while not qstate.empty():
            if qstate.get() == "stop":
                run = False
        TDC.ReadTDC(f)
    f.close()
```

I then define a p variable so I can use it globally (not sure if this is needed, I just did it to be safe), what follows is the Kivy implementation part:

```
p=0
def press_callback(obj)
    global tdcinit, q, p
    print("Button pressed,", obj.text)
    if obj.text == 'ReadTDC':
        if obj.state =="down":
            p = Process(target = readprocess, args=(q,))
            p.start()
        else:
            q.put("stop")
            p.join()
            TDC.Reset()
            print("Done Recording")
```

My TDC.Reset() function just calls it's Power On Reset Command listed in its documentation (stops measurements and re initializes). The updated function in the TDC library for ReadTDC is:

```
def ReadTDC(self,f):
    GPIO.output(29,0)
    i=8
    j=1
    self.__transfer(0x68)
    while i<32:
        byteback=self.__transfer(0x00)
        if j<4:
            f.write("Ref: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
            j=j+1
        elif j>=4 and j<6:
            f.write("Res: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
            j=j+1
        else:
            f.write("Res: %02X\r\n" % (byteback))
            j=1
        i=i+1
    f.write("\r\n")
    GPIO.output(29,1)
    return f
```

Hope this helps anyone searching for this, I do plan to make our TDC-GPX2, AD5592R (DAC/ADC Combo), and LMH6401 (Programmable Gain Amplifier) libraries public somehow (maybe Git?) after we get them fleshed out and working.

Answer (score -1):

I am doing something similar but with threading, and I'm looking to get away from it. So, while I cannot help you directly, maybe I can steer you to some documentation I too am going to be digging into soon.....

https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually just found this today and started poking through it. If I figure it out I'll post it here.